# Read data in blob storage in Databricks

Tags: python, azure, blob, databricks, azure-databricks

Trying to read my data in a blob storage from DataBricks

```
spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.account.key.ACCOUNTNAME.blob.core.windows.net",
  "MYKEY")
```

This should allow to connect to my storage blob

Then, according to [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html) it's should be easy to access file in my blob.

I tried many thing, nothing work

One example

```
blob_url = "https://ACCOUNTNAME.blob.core.windows.net/BLOBNAME/PATH/file"
df=pd.read_csv(blob_url)
```

return

> HTTP Error 404: The specified resource does not exist.

Any idea? I can show all my attempts with error message if needed

Another error

```
%scala

dbutils.fs.ls("wasbs://ACCOUNTNAME@BLOBNAME.blob.core.windows.net/PATH")
```

> shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: Container BLOBNAME in account ACCOUNTNAME.blob.core.windows.net not found, and we can't create it using anoynomous credentials, and no credentials found for them in the configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may checkout the below code to read data from blob storage using Azure Databricks.

```
# Set up an account access key:
# Get Storage account Name and 

spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.chepra.blob.core.windows.net", "gv7nVISerl8wbK9mPGm8TC3CQIEjV3Z5dQxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxldlOiA==")
df = spark.read.csv("wasbs://sampledata@chepra.blob.core.windows.net/Azure/AzureCostAnalysis.csv", header="true")
df.show()
```

[image]

For dbutils.fs.ls no need to use magic cells like %scala, you may use the below code to results all the files in the container:

```
# Get file information 
dbutils.fs.ls("wasbs://sampledata@chepra.blob.core.windows.net/Azure")
```

[image]

Hope this helps. Do let us know if you any further queries.

Comment: I have error message `shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.`

Comment: Could you please double check the storage key and storage container name which you are using?